# How to frame XML String Request in WSO2 esb

Tags: xslt, xpath, wso2, xquery, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1,
I wish to frame the string request in wso2esb for that I am using Xquery.
I have tried with string function in xquery but I am getting errors
my xquery is like this

```
<x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
  declare namespace env="http://eai.googl.afr/Envelope";
  declare namespace kls="http://eai.klsdop.inso/klsservice";
  declare variable $Id as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Name as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Message as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $PHNO as xs:string+ external;

  element{'kls:XInput'}{
  element{'kls:XData'}{string(
  <DATA>      
    <REQUEST ID_VALUE="{$Id}" NAME_VALUE="{$Name}" MESSAGE_VALUE="{$Message}" USER_TYPE="Daimond" PHNO_VALUE="{$PHNO}" ></REQUEST>
</DATA>)
  }
  }
```

So above xquery I am using to frame the below STRING request

```
    <kls:XInput>
    <kls:XData>
         <DATA>
 <REQUEST ID_VALUE="5" NAME_VALUE="Faisal" MESSAGE_VALUE="Who" USER_TYPE="Daimond" PHNO_VALUE="65879541212" ></REQUEST>
</DATA>
 </kls:XInput>
  </kls:XData>
```

But I am getting error in wso2esb like this.Because every time values will change.

```
[2014-11-14 16:23:44,375] ERROR - XQueryMediator Error during the querying No ex
ternal variable named **Id** exists in the query
javax.xml.xquery.XQException: No external variable named **Id** exists in the qu
ery
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDynamicContext.bindExternalVariable(SaxonXQDy
namicContext.java:225)
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDynamicContext.bindObject(SaxonXQDynamicConte
xt.java:154)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.bindVariable(XQuer
yMediator.java:594)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.performQuery(XQuer
yMediator.java:311)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.mediate(XQueryMedi
ator.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(Pro
xyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
```

Why its giving error like, I am passing the values from my proxy service through Xquery mediator.
My proxy is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Example" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="a" value="values" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <xquery key="AddStringExample">
                <variable name="Id" value="25" type="STRING"/>
                <variable name="Name" value="fisudal" type="STRING"/>
                <variable name="Message" value="Who r u" type="STRING"/>
                <variable name="PHNO" value="123456" type="STRING"/>
                 </xquery>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

Is anybody know how to resolve this. Is there any solution to do this same in XSLT
thanks in advance.

Comment: In Orcle Osb we can able to achive this using fn-bea:serialize() function but how to do in wso2esb

Comment: If I use the same function in wso2 esb its giving error like this  [2014-11-17 12:18:54,027] ERROR - XQueryMediator Error during the querying Canno
t find a matching 0-argument function named {http://www.bea.com/xquery/xquery-fu
nctions}serialize()
javax.xml.xquery.XQException: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {
http://www.bea.com/xquery/xquery-functions}serialize()
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.newXQException(SaxonXQConnection.j
ava:195)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work for you.

```
    <x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
  declare namespace env="http://eai.googl.afr/Envelope";
  declare namespace kls="http://eai.klsdop.inso/klsservice";
  declare variable $Id as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Name as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Message as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $PHNO as xs:string+ external;

  element{'kls:XInput'}{
  element{'kls:XData'}{
  element{'kls:DATA'}{
  element{'REQUEST'}{concat('REQUEST ID_VALUE=','"',$Id,'" ','NAME_VALUE=','"',$Name,'" ','MESSAGE_VALUE=','"',$Message,'" ','USER_TYPE=','"','Daimond','" ','PHNO_VALUE=','"',$PHNO,'"')}
  }
  }
  }
  </x>
```